# Wouldn't a better term for smoking Crystal meth be condensing or vaporizing?

Tags: terminology, drugs

There isn't actually any chemical reaction taking place.  The meth is heated, first it melts, then it vaporizes, but in the process it doesn't mix with other chemicals.  It just merely changes state.  Smoke, as I understand it is a chemical reaction.  it combines with oxygen and releases smoke and ash, the end product is 2 entirely different chemicals.

Not that it really matters, people are probably going to go on calling it smoke anyway, and not that I condone illicit drug use in any way, but was just curious, technically is it smoke or vapor that is inhaled?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what takes place when crystal meth is "smoked".  But, yes, *if* it's the case that, in "smoking" crystal meth, all users are doing is converting it (and the other substances with which it is mixed) to the vapor state (rather than combusting them) then vaping, rather than smoking, would be more technically correct.